# Como direcionar um link para uma das abas de um list group do Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html5, funções, bootstrap-4

preciso acessar uma aba de um list group do bootstrap 4 a partir de um link de outra página.

Na primeira página eu tenho:
link1
link2
link3

Quando eu clicar no link2, quero que vá para a outra página e já caia direto na aba do list group condizente (link2). Mas por padrão, sempre vem com o primeiro link amostra (usando o a classe 'show').

Nas abas estão: 
link1
link2
link3

Pensei na seguinte alternativa:

Quando eu clicar no link1 eu direciono para a página mas na url eu já coloco o id da list tab ficando assim:

> ...com/pagina.html#link2

E então eu aplico a seguinte função:

```
<script>
var url = location.href;  // pega o url da página
var string = url.split('#'); // aqui faz a quebra da linha na #
var valor = string[1]; // aqui atribui o valor a variavel 
</script>
```

Minha variavel **valor** passa a ter o valor de 'link2'

Minha ideia era fazer uma condicionante simples:

**Se valor = 'id-do-link2' clicar no link com o id da tab que eu quero.**

Assim, ao clicar na primeira página, o nav roda a função, verifica qual id está a url e já carrega a tab correta.

Entenderam? Deve ter ficado confuso! Conseguem me ajudar com essa funçãozinha simples? Se variavel contém string clicar no elemento tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode disparar um click no link da aba de forma automática:

```
var url = location.href;
var string = url.split('#');
var valor = string[1];
$("a[href='#"+valor+"']").click(); // dispara o click
```

Repare que o click será na aba que possui o `href` igual o hash na URL.

Para alterar a URL no navegador de acordo com a aba clicada, pode usar a função `history.replaceState()`:

```
$("#myTab a").on("click", function(){
   history.replaceState(null, null, $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

> Não esqueça de trocar o id `#myTab` pelo id da sua lista onde estão as
>   abas.

Comment: Mandou bem demais Sam, só a primeira linha do código que adicionaste já resolveu o problema! Obrigado!